# Three.js + Firefox 31 on OSX = skewed renders?

Tags: firefox, three.js

Working on my Three.js app, I noticed that some of my three.js canvases started rendering skewed. Investigating, it occurs on OSX under Firefox 31 and not just my work, but in many of the three.js featured examples:

[image: skewed render under osx and firefox 31]

[image: another skewed render under osx and firefox 31]

Anyone else seeing this, and maybe a workaround? Is this a bug in firefox 31's shader compiler? The version of three.js does not seem to matter either...

Comment: You are using a version of three.js that is 2 years old. Perhaps you can upgrade to the current version.

Comment: That's a funky error though! :D

Comment: I'm seeing this on examples using R68, such as http://potree.org/demo/potree_2014.05.23/examples/weiss_lifeboat.html

Comment: This one is R67, but it's the first example on the three.js examples page: https://www.batmanarkhamknight.com/en_US/batmobile.  And the three.js editor is R68 at http://threejs.org/editor/ All skewed sideways...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in firefox itself:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1018315